# The name 'Directory' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I create music player, because I'm learning how to write a Universal App. I'm trying to load a list of all songs in a folder but when I use the GetFiles, Visual Studio shows me the error: "

> The name 'Directory' does not exist in the current context"

even though at the beginning of the code I have "using System.IO". What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace project_2
{

    public sealed partial class Select : Page
    {
        private void add_new_song(int song_number)
        {...}

        private string[] load_songs()
        {
            string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\");
        }

        public Select()
        {...}

        private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {...}

    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is another `Directory` (probably as a variable) in your code and you get compiler error on _that_ line. Can you please show the relevant code?

Comment: This is the only place where I use the word "Directory" and the error indicates that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Directory` is not part of store apps SDK, and even if it would `GetFiles` would not exist as there are no synchronous methods in the SDK to access disc resources.

You are likely looking for [StoreageFolder.GetFilesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfilesasync.aspx) or similar API...